# Missing branch with when and enum when running Jacoco coverage

Tags: kotlin, jacoco

I using Jacoco 0.8.6 and I have an enum with 3 values.
I have this `when` shown on the image below and I have a test for each branch but Jacoco is still saying that I am missing a branch, also my `var` is non-null. What is wrong?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JaCoCo performs analysis of bytecode. For `Example.kt`

```
object Example {
    var type: Type = Type.SETUP_LOGIN
        set(value) {
            field = value
            when (value) {
                Type.SETUP_LOGIN -> nop()
                Type.CHANGE_PIN -> nop()
                Type.CHANGE_FINGERPRINT -> nop()
            }
        }

    fun nop() {
    }

    enum class Type {
        SETUP_LOGIN, CHANGE_PIN, CHANGE_FINGERPRINT
    }
}
```

compiled by

```
kotlinc-1.4.30/bin/kotlinc Example.kt
```

execution of

```
java -v -p Example.class
```

shows following bytecode for `setType` method

```
public final void setType(Example$Type);
    descriptor: (LExample$Type;)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_FINAL
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: aload_1
         1: ldc           #17                 // String value
         3: invokestatic  #23                 // Method kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V
         6: aload_1
         7: putstatic     #11                 // Field type:LExample$Type;
        10: aload_1
        11: getstatic     #29                 // Field Example$WhenMappings.$EnumSwitchMapping$0:[I
        14: swap
        15: invokevirtual #35                 // Method Example$Type.ordinal:()I
        18: iaload
        19: tableswitch   { // 1 to 3
                       1: 44
                       2: 51
                       3: 58
                 default: 65
            }
        44: aload_0
        45: invokevirtual #39                 // Method nop:()V
        48: goto          65
        51: aload_0
        52: invokevirtual #39                 // Method nop:()V
        55: goto          65
        58: aload_0
        59: invokevirtual #39                 // Method nop:()V
        62: goto          65
        65: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 4: 6
        line 5: 10
        line 6: 44
        line 7: 51
        line 8: 58
        line 9: 65
        line 10: 65
```

where as you can see `tableswitch` has 4 branches and this is exactly what you see in the JaCoCo report.

Looking at such bytecode only (as like JaCoCo does) there is no way to realize that `default` branch of `tableswitch` can't be reached - add one more value to enum, without changing anything else, recompile and you'll see exactly the same bytecode for this `setType` method.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah I've replaced the last branch with an else and it works

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exhaustive`

```
val <T> T.exhaustive: T
get() = this
```

then

```
when (value) {
    Type.SETUP_LOGIN -> nop()
    Type.CHANGE_PIN -> nop()
    Type.CHANGE_FINGERPRINT -> nop()
}.exhaustive
```